# MacOS create a notification if a ping fails?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to create a notification if a ping fails on MacOS?

I've seen this terminal notifier program http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/03/send-an-alert-to-notification-center-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/ which looks like it might be able to do it.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on any built in tools or scripts that may achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a one-liner I use in the terminal to ping a host once per second and beep (ring the terminal bell by emiting the ASCII “bell” control character) each time it fails:

```
pingwatch () { while sleep 1; do ping -c1 -t1 $1 || echo -e "\a"; done }
pingwatch 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: is this oascript? or? could it bring up a pop up in the notification pane instead of making a noise?

Comment: @AlexW It's a shell script, possibly bash-specific (I can never remember which bash features are bash-specific as opposed to being standard POSIX Bourne shell compliant). If you want to change how it notifies you, replace the `echo -e "\a"` with whatever you want. You could probably call out to osascript to pop up a dialog if you want. Beware that any interactions with osascript or the GUI might only work if you're sitting at the machine in question, not ssh'd into it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, MacOS ping has added the `-A` and `-a` flags for audible alerts.

- `-A` for audible alert when packet is not received (down detector)
- `-a` for audible alert when packet **is** received (up detector)

e.g. `ping -a 1.2.3.4` will sound the bell when host 1.2.3.4 is up.